# How to compile a GNU Radio application with Microsoft Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, gnuradio

Hello i'm trying to make a GNU Radio application using GNU Radio API.
My Setup :
Windows 10,
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013,
GNU Radio 3.8.1

I installed GNU Radio 3.8.1 from binaries on windows 10.
As my compiler doesn't find some libraries i add and build them:

- boost 1.74
- log4cpp 1.1.3
- mpir 3.0.0

I have a few errors during the compilation of my GNU Radio application.
Most of errors are located in the file : "rpccallbackregister_base.h" which is in GNU radio, but I never modified this file.

169 IntelliSense : missing base member or class name    rpccallbackregister_base.h  80  15
170 IntelliSense : missing base member or class name    rpccallbackregister_base.h  81  15
error C2612: trailing ')' illegal in base/member initializer list   rpcccallbackregister_base.h
error C2612: trailing ')' illegal in base/member initializer list   rpcccallbackregister_base.h

Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' \rpccallbackregister_base.h 80  1
Error   87  error C2059: syntax error : ')' \rpccallbackregister_base.h 80  1

---

Have you some idea about this problem ?
Is my installation wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that GNU Radio is using some gcc-specific extensions and may not be set up for Windows compatibility. You might have better luck compiling on a mingw or cygwin setup.